# Angular - Prevent other requests from going out if one returns 401 (Cancel the others)

Tags: angular

**Background**: I have a Angular Site with JWT Authentication and simple guard protecting the routes which is working as expected.

Let's say the token is expired, and *Route A* fires off three requests on the `ngOnInit()` lifecycle hook. I have an error interceptor which will catch the `401 Unauthorized` status code and redirect to login.

**Issue**:
When redirecting to login, the other two requests out of the three will also fail with `401 Unauthorized`.

**What I've tried:**
Using RxJS, I am using the `takeUntil()` function bound to an observable to listen for cancellation. I have it set to cancel all requests as soon as the first request fails, but I am finding that this place is too premature as the requests still go through.

- Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated?
- Should I care about the failed requests as the site functions as intended but just logs a bunch of failed requests to the console?

Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't care in your place. It doesn't affect anything on the client side, and implementing cancelling logic could just introduce new bugs to your application.

Comment: @Andrei Thanks for response, glad to hear a second opinion!